# What is a programming model?

Tags: design, architecture

I have read [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_model), but I still really do not know a programming model is. I saw it being used in the following [context](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set_architecture#Instruction_set_implementation):

> Any given instruction set can be implemented in a variety of ways. All
>   ways of implementing a particular instruction set provide the same
>   programming model, and all implementations of that instruction set are
>   able to run the same executables.

Could someone please try to help me understand what a programming model is?

Comment: The Wikipedia article references [another article](https://asc.llnl.gov/content/assets/docs/exascale-pmWG.pdf) that goes into much greater detail.  Have you tried reading that article?  Note that, if you don't have a significant educational or experiential background in computer science or software development, you might not understand that article either, nor are you likely to understand any answers we try to give you.

Comment: The good news is that you don't need to understand what the word means to be proficient in software development.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I do think that I should know enough about computer technology in order to understand these explanations... I just read that article i think that I am starting to understand the term.. It says that a "programming model" is " is an abstraction of the underlying computer system that allows for the expression of both algorithms and data structures" - So I get the abstract idea, but **I do not see how it is used and why it is even there?** So could you give me a real life example of a programming model?

Comment: The Operating System and its API.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Is the OS a programming model? How? :/ And also, why is there even a "programming model" - what is it good for?

Comment: The OS embodies a programming model by virtue of its design.  When an OS is designed, decisions have to be made about how it is to receive commands from the user's programs, how data is to be shared between different software modules, how software modules are to be constructed so that the OS can work with them, how concurrency is to be supported, and so forth.  Those decisions collectively form a "programming model."

Comment: In many operating systems, threads and processes form part of the programming model.

Comment: @RobertHarvey thanks! I totally understand the first comment, but can you elaborate a little on your second comment? Like, how can processes and threads form part of the programming model if it was the OS that constituted a programming model?

Comment: Processes and threads are maintained by the operating system.

Comment: @RobertHarvey but then, wouldn't the programming model solely be formed by the OS - if the processes, threads, etc. are part of the OS? I know that I might be asking a lot :))

Comment: An OS is just one way you can create a programming model.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Alright. So let me get this straight If we had an OS, some processes and some threads - would the OS form one programming model and the processes and threads would form another programming model or would the processes and threads adhere to the programming model formed by the OS (in this case, would they add anything to the model or simple use it)?

Comment: @RobertHarvey That would be the last question to you and then i'll stop bothering you :)

Comment: Go back to the "programming models" article.  It says: *"Programming models bridge the gap between the underlying hardware architecture and the supporting layers of software available to applications. Programming models are different from both programming languages and application programming interfaces (APIs). Specifically, a programming model is an abstraction of the underlying computer system that allows for the expression of both algorithms and data structures."*

Comment: *"In comparison, languages and APIs provide implementations of these abstractions and allow the algorithms and data structures to be put into
practice – a programming model exists independently of the choice of both the programming language and the supporting APIs."*

Comment: @asd most modern os's have a native threading model that they support but a program running under an OS can create it's own threading model that runs in one of the OS's threads. You can even run an entirely different OS (that may have its own threading model) under the host OS. All of which will need to be supported in some way by the CPU which might or might not help manage these threads depending on if you chose to use whatever model it has.

Comment: If threads and processes are part of the operating system, and you write software against these threads and processes, then the design decisions that resulted in those threads and processes form part of the *programming model* you are using.

Comment: No problem.  My last thought is that, while you'll probably never encounter this word in your professional practice (except in passing, or within the context of an extremely specific conversation), it's still useful as a mental exercise to think about what the word means.

Comment: I encountered this word in my job, for a very practical purpose: reading basics of GatewayScript.

Answer (score 9):

Here the programming model is what the instructions (the language) require to work correctly. Implementation of those instructions are the details that can change without changing the result of following those instructions.

For example, if my instructions are that you should relocate 3 feet north and 2 feet west you can implement those instructions by moving west first then north, north first then west, or by moving diagonally in a northwest direction. You can even stager about randomly until you happen be at the right spot and then stop. Any of those follow the instructions. The programming model here is the idea of relocating at a different spot. Is it not how you relocate at a different spot. "How" is implementation detail.

A programming language or an instruction set both abstract away implementation details that they do not care about. This leaves those who design compilers, interpreters, JVMs, and CPUs with room to make choices of how to implement while supporting this model. Those choices can make things more robust, efficient, maintainable, and extensible. Or they can fail to do so. But so long as they do what the instructions asked for they still maintain the programming model.

So long as the implementation supports the programming model you can trust that when it follows the instructions it will give you what it was supposed to give you.

Also understand that these can layer. You could have a movement model that exposes the idea of moving only north & south and east & west leaving no way to move diagonally. That detail won't be in the location model above but it will be down here in the movement model. What isn't in the movement model is if you walk, ride a bike, or swim to do these movements.

Whenever we model we chose things to care about at this level. Other things we abstract away and let something else deal with them.

Comment: Thank you! That helped too. However, Robert did actually answer my question - so you will just get an upvote filled with appreciation!